# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT postgres database

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean, connection-timeout

I have a Postgres database on digitalocean. I am able to connect to it from my pod in Kubernetes. However, when I try to connect to it using pgadmin, or sqlectron, I get connection timeouts.

`Error invoking remote method 'DB_CONNECT': Error: connect ETIMEDOUT`

The logs show that it connects, then times out. Please what am I missing?

I have added my ip address to the trusted sources for the database.
[image]

Comment: What is it in your pod in Kubernetes which can connect?  Are pgadmin and sqlectron also in pods in Kubernetes?